# JSON API wordpress plugin response is sometimes too slow

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Sometimes the response (in json format) provided by `JSON API` wordpress plugin is too slow.
*Is there any way to cache the `json` response ?*

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API